# How to read until EOF from STDOUT in C?

Tags: c, string, dynamic, malloc, stdout

#1: I do not know the size of output produced by stdout, given a command.

#2: I don't want to use char array like

```
char buffer[1024];
```

as it will result in memory shortage or wastage.

#3: If I use character pointer like

```
char *buffer;
```

I will have to allocate allocate memory for it like

```
buffer = (char *)malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
```

#4: If I use getc() within while loop like

```
char *buf, c;
int i=0, j=1;
int pipefd[2];
int  stdout_bk;
code[message_read] = '\0';
stdout_bk = dup(fileno(stdout));
pipe(pipefd);
dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

system(code);
close(pipefd[1]);

dup2(stdout_bk, STDOUT_FILENO);
buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

while(c!=End_Of_File) // What should I replace End_Of_File with?
{
    c = getc(pipefd[0]);
    buf = (char*)realloc(buf, j * sizeof(char));
    buf[i] = c;
    i++;
    j++;
}
```

I do not know what is the End_Of_file for the stdout data.

P.S.: the program runs a command, e.g., system("setarch x86_64 -R dd if=/proc/self/maps | grep bin/dd") or system("ls -al") and I need to get the STDOUT. For that I have used dup2 and need to pipe the output to a buffer.

NOTE: the output can be of variable length.

Comment: I think there are lots of questions on this topic already, so just a comment: declare `c` as an `int` (not `char`), replace `while(c!=End_Of_File)` with `while ((c=getc(stdin)) != EOF)` (replace `stdin` with whatever), and get rid of the call to `get()` in the next line.

Comment: Calling realloc for each and every character is uncommon, even if I think that it is internally optimized to allocate larger chunks.

Comment: Why not use POSIX standard function [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html)
to get a file stream that contains the output of the command you give it.  You have quite a lot of plumbing problems with your pipes; using `popen()` will avoid most of them.

Comment: How much main memory does your system have that you think a 1 KiB buffer is going to cause trouble?  On most non-embedded systems, you could allocate 64 KiB and not cause any trouble.  You would want to avoid megabyte buffers on the stack; the stack is limited to 1 MiB on Windows by default (usually 8 MiB on Unix-like systems).

Comment: The code in your #4 will only work with very small outputs, since it doesn't start reading until the executed command terminates. That means that it is relying on the pipe to act as a buffer for the entire output. Pipes do buffer, but their capacity to do so is limited; once you fill the pipe buffer, writing to it will block meaning your program will effectively deadlock. If you're using Linux, read [man 7 pipe](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) for more details (paying particular attention to "Pipe Capacity"). Or read any good text on IPC.

Comment: A note on the title: your program is not reading from stdout.  It is reading from stdin.  The write side of the pipe it is reading from is the  stdout of the program writing to it, but your process is not reading from stdout.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with your code:

- `c` must be defined with type `int`
- `getc()` cannot take a system handle as an argument, you must wrap that in a `FILE*` with `fdopen()`.
- `End_Of_File` for data returned by `getc()` is simply `EOF` and `c` must have type `int` for end of file testing to be reliable.
- reallocating the array one byte at a time is inefficient and might be more wasteful than reallocating by chunks
- more importantly you might want to allocate one extra byte for a null terminator if you intend to use this buffer as a C string.
- the output of the `system()` command will be limited to the size of the system pipe buffers, usually around 5KB, so your program will get stuck for any larger output.
- it is much simpler to use `popen()` for your purpose.

Here is a simplified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char code[] = "ls -lR";
    char *buf = NULL;
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = popen(code, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "popen error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        buf = (char *)realloc(buf, i + 2);
        if (buf == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
            pclose(fp);
            return 1;
        }
        buf[i++] = (char)c;
    }
    pclose(fp);
    printf("output: %d bytes\n", i);
    if (buf != NULL) {
        buf[i] = '\0';
        fputs(buf, stdout);
    }
    free(buf);        
    return 0;
}
```